# how to authorize by rest api for neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j-enterprise 2.2, HA mode.

Now when I access the neo4j instance by rest api, I got 401 response, it seems that this is because of Unauthorized ?

My question is how can I authorize in rest API? 
  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In short: you need to send one request to retrieve a token by sending your username/password. Subsequent requests will use the token.

In detail: read the [related section in the manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0-M02/rest-api-security.html).